# I am trying to run ubuntu on my imac and it keeps showing 4 not readable screens

Tags: mac

[The Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58fYZ.jpg)

I have tried this with arch Linux and tails. same thing. when i actually start and ubuntu asks me which version I would like to run and it works fine. but then it starts up the os and this happens. i can give more details.